# Text input inside a radio button?

Tags: wordpress, accessibility

Gravity Forms for WordPress has an option for its radio button sets called 'Enable "other" choice'. This option adds a text input nested inside the option.

GF's radio buttons are a problem to begin with since they have no fieldset, but ignoring that, this other choice causes problems with keyboard accessibility. When you tab to the group of radio buttons, you're fine, but as soon as you tab again the focus goes to the "Other" text input, your radio button selection changes to that, and there is no way to change the radio button back to any other value.

The code for one of these monsters is:

```
<li id='field_4_4' class='gfield gfield_contains_required field_sublabel_below field_description_below gfield_visibility_visible' >
    <label class='gfield_label'  >
        Overall label that applies to all of the options
    </label>
    <div class='ginput_container ginput_container_radio'>
        <ul class='gfield_radio' id='input_4_4'>
            <li class='gchoice_4_4_0'>
                <input name='input_4' type='radio' value='First option'  id='choice_4_4_0' tabindex='14'    />
                <label for='choice_4_4_0' id='label_4_4_0'>
                First option</label>
            </li>
            <li class='gchoice_4_4_1'>
                <input name='input_4' type='radio' value='Second option'  id='choice_4_4_1' tabindex='15'    />
                <label for='choice_4_4_1' id='label_4_4_1'>
                Second option</label>
            </li>
            <li class='gchoice_4_4_2'>
                <input name='input_4' type='radio' value='Third option'  id='choice_4_4_2' tabindex='16'    />
                <label for='choice_4_4_2' id='label_4_4_2'>
                Third option</label>
            </li>
            <li class='gchoice_4_4_3'>
                <input name='input_4' type='radio' value='gf_other_choice'  id='choice_4_4_3' tabindex='17'   onfocus="jQuery(this).next('input').focus();" />
                <input id='input_4_4_other' name='input_4_other' type='text' value='Other' aria-label='Other' onfocus='jQuery(this).prev("input")[0].click(); if(jQuery(this).val() == "Other") { jQuery(this).val(""); }' onblur='if(jQuery(this).val().replace(" ", "") == "") { jQuery(this).val("Other"); }' tabindex='17'   />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
```

Is there any way to make this radio button group accessible? I know I could un-check 'Enable "other" choice' and create "Other" as a normal radio button, then add a separate text input that is a conditional field to get around this. The problem is it's on a site with multiple editors who add and edit forms, and they're nontechnical users who may use this option themselves sometimes - so I'd like to find a way to make it work if it's even possible.

Comment: Right now I just want to know what parts of the HTML markup need to be changed to make the whole thing keyboard accessible. I'll figure out how to bully Gravity Forms into spitting it out as a separate task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took 3 steps:
1. Add a label to the radio button
2. Remove tabindexes
3. Add CSS

Here's the updated HTML:

```
<li class='gchoice_4_4_3'>
    <!-- no more tabindex -->
    <input name='input_4' type='radio' value='gf_other_choice'  id='choice_4_4_3' onfocus="jQuery(this).next('input').focus();" />
    <!-- new label -->
    <label for='choice_4_4_3'>Other</label>
    <!-- no more tabindex -->
<input id='input_4_4_other' name='input_4_other' type='text' value='Other' aria-label='Other' onfocus='jQuery(this).prev("input")[0].click(); if(jQuery(this).val() == "Other") { jQuery(this).val(""); }' onblur='if(jQuery(this).val().replace(" ", "") == "") { jQuery(this).val("Other"); }'  />
</li>
```

And the CSS, which hides the text input by default but displays it when the "other" radio button is selected:

```
.gfield_radio li input[type="text"] { display:none; }
.gfield_radio li input:checked + label + input[type="text"] { display:block; }
```

The CSS went into my custom theme and the filter to change the HTML is:

```
add_filter('gform_tabindex', function($tabindex, $form) {
    return false;
}, 10, 2);
```

It would be nice if Gravity Forms would get with the times and set everything in a `<fieldset>` like it's supposed to, but at least with these changes, the "other" radio button is now keyboard accessible.

Comment: I've been looking all over for an accessible version of this pattern. But I noticed the `onFocus` event doesn't find the next input when you re-order the HTML. Did you happen to make any other changes you could share?

Comment: I started using a plugin called "WCAG 2.0 form fields for Gravity Forms" which helps some.

Comment: I appreciate the reply! Thanks, i will check it out.

Comment: PS- I will probably try to make the script and classes a bit more generic (since I'm not using Gravity Forms) but here's [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/helgatheviking/8kpca5t3/19/) with it working.